# Account activation time out in PHP & general PHP help

Tags: php

I was wondering because I can code in PHP without minors hitches or errors but one thing I have never understood about PHP is the fact it is a server side scripting language, so it needs something to trigger it, if this is so how can I create a PHP file which runs routine checks? and example is:

Someone has not activated there account although they have had a email sent out to them and it has been the time period given, were and how would the script run, would it need to be required into a page or is there a function for this.

Thanks in advance, I just need this clearing up a little it if's not too much trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you would usually set up a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cron) job.

cron is a daemon that periodically starts other programs, for tasks such as the one you outline. You can make cron start php scripts, as well.

If you're on shared hosting, there's probably an option somewhere in your control panel to set up a periodic cron job.

Otherwise, here are some guides on doing it manually:

- [Cron Tutorial – Managing cron tab or cron job is Easy!](http://www.webmasters-central.com/article-blog/tutorials/cron-tutorial-managing-cron-tab-or-cron-job-is-easy/)
- [Newbie: Intro to cron](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)
- [Cron Tutorial](http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html)
- [Running PHP Scripts with Cron](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Unix/Linux system, you can write a php script that can be [executed from command-line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php) and add it as a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job.